# How to create deep object with dynamic name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
var array1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
```

and I'm trying to get something like this

```
{
  alphabetical: {
    a: {
      a.json: "Alpha",
      a1.json: "Alpha1"
    }
    b: {
      b.json: "Beta",
      b1.json: "Beta1"
    }
    c: {
      c.json: "Charlie",
      c1.json: "Charlie1"
    }
  }
}
```

The only thing I can hard code is `alphabetical` and the rest I don't know the data at all.

Right now this is what I have so far:

```
localeObject[locale] = Object(data.last_update);


{
"alphabetical": {
    "a": "Alpha1",
    "b": "Beta1"
  }
}
```

Update:

```
    localeObject[locale] = {};
    localeObject[locale][fileName] = {};
    localeObject[locale][fileName] = data.last_update
```

Right now I can get it to this point but the "a", "b" still always being overwrite by the last object that is being pushed in.

Comment: You probably understand your problem, but from your question, I don't get what your question is. I don't get how you are going from your array to the class.

Comment: @attila I'm so sorry for not  being clear on my question... That array is related on putting it as a nested key name. I'll update my question as soon as I get back from outside